# Xcode 4.4 unit test

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, testing

First time trying to add unit test to my Xcode project. I added a test (LogicTests.h, LogicTests.m), linked it to a project in Target Dependencies. After that I created sample-class FDUnitTestClass and I want to test it with adding a simple math operation in it with logging result to Debug console. But I don't understand right way to do this. Do I need to define a method in .m of FDUnitTestClass, and if so how I can invoke it to see the log in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some links that can help you:

1. [Xcode Unit Testing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html)
2. [Unit Testing in Xcode 4 Quick Start Guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide)